# Something that can not be undone or undo

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, meaning-in-context

A word for something that can't be undone or undo ?

Comment: permanent? irreversible? You can try these in a thesaurus.

Comment: Please show the results of your own research to save others repeating it.

Comment: `non-repudiable` is one that doesn’t show up in most thesaurus, but I added it to powerthesaurus.org

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"irreversible"

```
 -  not able to be undone or altered.
 - not able to be reversed.
```

[source.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Irreversible)

or

"irrevocable"

```
not able to be revoked, changed, or undone.
```

[source.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/irrevocable)

Answer (score 2):

Synonyms for "permanent" from NOAD 2011:

lasting, enduring, indefinite, continuing, perpetual, everlasting, eternal, abiding, constant, irreparable, irreversible, lifelong, indissoluble, indelible, standing, perennial, unending, endless, never-ending, immutable, undying, imperishable, indestructible, ineradicable, ineliminable; literary sempiternal, perdurable, long-term, stable, secure, durable.

Synonyms for "secure" from NOAD 2011:

fastened, fixed, secured, done up; closed, shut, locked, safe, protected, sheltered, certain, assured, reliable, dependable, settled, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

not a single word but

**written in stone** (or **carved in stone**/**engraved in stone**)

> Fig. permanent or not subject to change. (Often in the negative.) Now, this isn't carved in stone yet, but this looks like the way it's going to be. Is this policy carved in stone, or can it still be modified? - *The Free Dictionary*

Like the definition says - it is usually used in the negative, but you can use it the other way for emphasis as well.

Answer (score 0):

"At(or beyond) the point of no return"